# string.match works but string.find failed in cocos lua on Android when using Chinese

Tags: lua, cocos2d-android

I use `string.find('中国', '中')` and `string.match('中国', '中')` to search in cocos lua.

It's weird that they both worked on Win32, however, string.find('中国', '中') failed on Android.

I read the source code of lua. http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html#str_find_aux

It seems that `lmemfind` and `match` works diffently on different platforms.

```
static int str_find (lua_State *L) {
  return str_find_aux(L, 1);
}


static int str_match (lua_State *L) {
  return str_find_aux(L, 0);
}

static int str_find_aux (lua_State *L, int find) {
  size_t l1, l2;
  const char *s = luaL_checklstring(L, 1, &l1);
  const char *p = luaL_checklstring(L, 2, &l2);
  ptrdiff_t init = posrelat(luaL_optinteger(L, 3, 1), l1) - 1;
  if (init < 0) init = 0;
  else if ((size_t)(init) > l1) init = (ptrdiff_t)l1;
  if (find && (lua_toboolean(L, 4) ||  /* explicit request? */
      strpbrk(p, SPECIALS) == NULL)) {  /* or no special characters? */
    /* do a plain search */
    const char *s2 = lmemfind(s+init, l1-init, p, l2);
    if (s2) {
      lua_pushinteger(L, s2-s+1);
      lua_pushinteger(L, s2-s+l2);
      return 2;
    }
  }
  else {
    MatchState ms;
    int anchor = (*p == '^') ? (p++, 1) : 0;
    const char *s1=s+init;
    ms.L = L;
    ms.src_init = s;
    ms.src_end = s+l1;
    do {
      const char *res;
      ms.level = 0;
      if ((res=match(&ms, s1, p)) != NULL) {
        if (find) {
          lua_pushinteger(L, s1-s+1);  /* start */
          lua_pushinteger(L, res-s);   /* end */
          return push_captures(&ms, NULL, 0) + 2;
        }
        else
          return push_captures(&ms, s1, res);
      }
    } while (s1++ < ms.src_end && !anchor);
  }
  lua_pushnil(L);  /* not found */
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494176/string-find-failed-on-chinese-character-in-android-but-success-on-pc-when-develo ?

Comment: I find string.match is available, so I really want to know what the difference is.